# Typo3 staticpub extension not publishing static files 

Tags: typo3

I installed [staticpub](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/staticpub/current/) extension,but its not working.

this is my crawler configuration

```
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets.test = &L=[0-5]
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets.test {
    cHash = 1
    procInstrFilter = tx_indexedsearch_reindex, tx_indexedsearch_crawler 


    }

 tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets {
  staticpub = &L=[|_TABLE:pages_language_overlay;_FIELD:sys_language_uid]
  staticpub.procInstrFilter = tx_staticpub_publish

}
```

I updated following lines in localconf.php also i created *staticpub* directory in root of my website.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['staticpub']['publishDir'] = '_staticpub_/';
```

I found not record in tx_staticpub_pages table. Also no file in *staticpub* directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use that feature! It's silly and useless and [has been removed](http://git.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/Core.git?a=commit;h=d690f818e4eefb54c90e59dd14519c92a94f5322) from TYPO3 for the upcoming version 4.6.

Please use e.g. [EXT:nc_staticfilecache](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/nc_staticfilecache/current/)